# How to merge a folder full of .txt files in a new .txt file preserving the encoding?

Tags: python, string, encoding, io

I have a folder with a lot of very large .txt files they look like this:

```
File1:

eta eta NCFS000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1


File2:
eta eta NCFS000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1

File3:
eta eta NCFS000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1
.
.
.
FileN
eta eta NCFS000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1
```

Could anybody help me with another aproach for this task?, another problem is the codification, the file is in spanish, i would like to preserve punctuation symbols, like accents and stuff like that. I would like to merge from File1 to FileN in a new_file i.e.:

new_file:

```
eta eta NCFS000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1
eta eta NCFS000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1
eta eta NCFS000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1
eta eta NCFS000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
buena bueno AQ0FS0 1
```

This is what i tried:

```
import os


def concatFiles():
    path = '/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt\'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for idx, infile in enumerate(files):
        print ("File #" + str(idx) + "  " + infile)
    concat = ''.join([open(path + f).read() for f in files])
    with open("output_concatFile.txt", "w") as fo:
        fo.write(path + concat)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    concatFiles()
```

the output_contacFile.txt have encoding troubles, i would like to preserve accents and spanish symbols, for example some words look like this:

```
est√° estar VAIP3S0
```

The correct output would be like:

```
está estar VAIP3S0
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could do this as a one-liner without touching Python: `cat folder/full/of/etc/* > output_concateFile.txt`.

Comment: Anyway, what's _wrong_ with what you tried?

Comment: I have this exception:File #2311  Teka_TK2_1280__Opinion_2039705.html.txt
    concat = ''.join([open(path + f).read() for f in files])
File #2312  Teka_TK2_1280__Opinion_2085252.html.txt
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt.DS_Store'

Comment: I would like another pythonic aproach..

Comment: `concat = ''.join([open(os.path.join(path , f)).read() for f in files])` or if you really dont want to use os.path.join use `path +"/"+ f`

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious. The file that exists is `/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt.DS_Store`, there is no such file, but there is a file named `/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt/.DS_Store`, so you missed a `/` in there.

Comment: One last thing: Do you need these in any particular order? [`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) explicitly says it gives results in arbitrary order. In practice, it's in the directory's native iteration order, which on most filesystems is probably going to be alphabetical order, but (a) that still means that, e.g., `File10.txt` is going to come before `File9.txt`, and (b) you may not want to rely on "… most … probably" anyway.

Comment: Yes, i need that order.

Comment: Another thing is that when i run the script i have problems with the ASCII encoding, please check the edit.

Comment: @samsmith: Which order is "that order"?

Comment: @samsmith: Also, "I have problems with the ASCII encoding" implies that you're probably using Python 3 here. My answer already explains how to solve that.

Comment: the order of the files in the folder

Comment: Im not using python 3, im using python 2.7.8

Comment: _Which_ order of the files in the folder? The order that Finder shows? The order that `ls` with no flags shows? Or the order that `os.listdir` happens to give you?

Comment: The order that ´ls´ shows

Answer (score 2):

Zeroth, note that this entire program could be done without Python, as a one-liner on the shell: `cat /Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt/* > output_concatFile.txt`.

First, to fix your problem, as Joran Beasley explains, you've just forgotten the `/` between the directory path and the filename. And errors like this are exactly why you want to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) instead of manipulating paths like dumb strings.

Next, instead of reading all the files into memory before writing anything, why not read them one by one?

Even better, instead of reading a whole file at a time, do it a buffer at a time; that way, if you accidentally drop a 36GB file in that directory, you won't try to read the whole thing into memory and throw your computer into swap hell. The [`copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) function does this for you automatically (although looping over [`iter(f.read(8192), b'')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) would also work fine).

Also, it's probably not a good idea to try to open potentially thousands of files without closing any of them.

If you want to preserve the contents *exactly*, especially if this is Python 3.x, you probably want binary mode. (You *could* instead open the files in Unicode text mode with the right encoding—the particular mojibake you're seeing is caused by treating UTF-8 text as if it were MacRoman, which should tell you how to fix it. But why make things difficult? Just copy the bytes as bytes.)

Finally, if you need to guarantee that the files show up in the order `ls` shows… well, Python doesn't guarantee that; in fact, [`listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) explicitly says "The list is in arbitrary order." But `ls` is guaranteed to be in lexicographical order, which is the same default order that Python uses for sorting strings. (In practice, `listdir` will almost always give you the native directory order, and that will usually be lexicographical order, so you *probably* won't need this. But you shouldn't trust that.)

So:

```
def concatFiles():
    path = '/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    with open("output_concatFile.txt", "wb") as fo:
        for f in sorted(files):
            with open(os.path.join(path, f), "rb") as fi:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fi, fo)
```

Comment: Still the same: r√°pido r√°pido

Comment: @samsmith: How are you looking at these files? Because if you've got some UTF-8 text files, and you concatenate them in binary mode, the result will be a UTF-8 text file. If you then view the resulting file as if it were MacRoman text, it's going to be mojibaked, but the same would be true if you viewed the original files as MacRoman.

Comment: i don't know, how can i know in what format are the .txt files?

Comment: @samsmith: Well, that's the big problem: text files don't know what encoding they're in, because all they have in them is the encoded text. So, that information has to come from somewhere else. That's why `str.decode` in Python takes an `encoding` argument, why HTTP's `Content-Type` header has an `encoding` attribute, etc. But again: How are you looking at these files? `cat` in the terminal? TextEdit? Some other program or app?

Answer (score 2):

You can write as your read instead of reading all the files into memory first, just write to the outfile as you iterate over each file:

```
def concatFiles():
    path = '/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    with open("output_concatFile.txt", "w") as fo: 
        for infile in files:
            with open(os.path.join(path, infile)) as fin:
                for line in fin:
                    fo.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `cat` in Python if you need a Python solution for some reason:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print line,
```

Save it to `cat.py` and to merge all .txt files in a folder, run:

```
$ python -mcat /Users/you/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt/*.txt > output_concatFile.txt
```

Here's [`cat.py` for Python 3](https://gist.github.com/zed/cda879d141081e5764bd).